# Need to get MORE than one result from the entity manager

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

I've been trying to figure this one out for the last little while.  In complete contrast to all those questions asking how to only get *one* result from a JPA query, I need **more** than one result - I need all of them.  I end up calling the entity manager's `find()` method, but it doesn't get me all of the nested results.

'Parent' class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LANGUAGE")  
public class LanguageData extends PersistedAuditedData<Long> {

@Id
@Column
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "ISO6391ALPHA2CODE")
private String iso6391Alpha2Code;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "languageData")
@MapKeyColumn(name = "LANGUAGE_ID")
private Map<Long, LanguageDataLocalization> localizations;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "localizationLanguage")
@MapKeyColumn(name = "LANGUAGE_LOCALIZATION_ID")
private Map<Long, LanguageDataLocalization> languagesLocalized;

/**
 * Private no-arg constructor for reflection-based 
     * construction inside JPA providers.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private LanguageData() {
    // Fields initialized by JPA.
}

    // Plus getters for the fields.

}
```

'Child' class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LANGUAGE_LOCALIZATION")
public class LanguageDataLocalization extends PersistedAuditedData<LanguageLocalizationKey>{

@EmbeddedId
private LanguageLocalizationKey id;

@Column(name = "REFERENCE_NAME")
private String name;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "LANGUAGE_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private LanguageData languageData;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "LANGUAGE_LOCALIZATION_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private LanguageData localizationLanguage;

/**
 * Private no-arg constructor for reflection-based JPA provider instantiation.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private LanguageDataLocalization() {
    // Fields initialized by JPA.
}

    // Plus getters for fields.
}
```

Key for 'Child' class.

```
@Embeddable
public class LanguageLocalizationKey {

@Column(name = "LANGUAGE_ID")
private Long languageId;

@Column(name = "LANGUAGE_LOCALIZATION_ID")
private Long languageLocalizationId;

/**
 * No-arg constructor, for use by JPA provider implementation.
 * <h1>DO NOT USE!</h1>
 * <p>Ideally, this should be <code>private</code>, 
     * however OpenJPA doesn't appear to be allowing that at the moment   
 * (unsure of cause).  This constructor does not initialize any data.</p>
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public LanguageLocalizationKey() {
    // Field initialization performed by JPA provider.
}

    // Plus getters
}
```

And used like so:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
private Collection<LanguageDataLocalization> getLocalizationsById(final Long id, final Collection<String> localeCodes) {
    try {
        if (localeCodes == null || localeCodes.isEmpty()) {
            final LanguageData data = entityManager.find(LanguageData.class, id);
            if (data == null) {
                return Collections.emptyList();
            } else {
                return data.getlocalizations().values();
            }
        } else {
            List<LanguageDataLocalization> results = entityManager.createNamedQuery("FIND_LANGUAGE_BY_ID", LanguageDataLocalization.class)
                                                                    .setParameter("iso6391Alpha2Codes", localeCodes)
                                                                    .setParameter("languageId", id)
                                                                    .getResultList();
            return results;
        }
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        // TODO: add logging
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

With `named-queries.xml` defined like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="1.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm
                    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd ">

<named-query name="FIND_LANGUAGE_BY_ID">
    <query>
        SELECT localized 
        FROM LanguageDataLocalization localized
        JOIN localized.localizationLanguage local
        WHERE localized.id.languageId = :languageId
        AND local.iso6391Alpha2Code IN :iso6391Alpha2Codes
    </query>
</named-query>
</entity-mappings>
```

`LANGUAGE` data (Derby in-memory database, pretty sure that's not important):

```
ID,  ISO6391ALPHA2CODE
123, en
137, fr
```

`LANGUAGE_LOCALIZATION` data

```
LANGUAGE_ID, LANGUAGE_LOCALIZATION_ID, REFERENCE_NAME
123,         123,                      English
123,         137,                      anglais
```

The actual problem is that when queried *without* any locale data (`localeCodes` is null or empty), `data.getLocalizations().values()` after the `entityManager.find()` returns a list of only *one* of the localized language-name data (the french one, but I'm assuming that's SQL 'random').  I **am** able to get both localizations if I explicitly query for them (either singly or together), so I know the data's *there*, and that the JPQL query works.

What can I do to make it return both (all, when I have localization data for more than 2 languages) localizations when not queried for a specific one?

---

The actual query seems to be this (some result columns removed):

```
SELECT t0.LANGUAGE_ID, t0.LANGUAGE_LOCALIZATION_ID, 
       t1.ISO6391ALPHA2CODE, 
       t0.REFERENCE_NAME 
FROM LANGUAGE_LOCALIZATION t0 
LEFT OUTER JOIN LANGUAGE t1 
ON t0.LANGUAGE_LOCALIZATION_ID = t1.id 
WHERE t0.LANGUAGE_ID = ? [params=?]
```

Which doesn't appear to be restricting the row count in any fashion. (`to.LANGUAGE_ID` matches more than one row).  Especially because, over the same dataset, the following gets both result rows (some result columns removed again):

```
SELECT t0.LANGUAGE_ID, t0.LANGUAGE_LOCALIZATION_ID, 
       t2.id, t2.ISO6391ALPHA2CODE, 
       t3.id, t3.ISO6391ALPHA2CODE, 
       t0.REFERENCE_NAME 
FROM LANGUAGE_LOCALIZATION t0 
INNER JOIN LANGUAGE t1 
ON t0.LANGUAGE_LOCALIZATION_ID = t1.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN LANGUAGE t2 
ON t0.LANGUAGE_ID = t2.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN LANGUAGE t3 
ON t0.LANGUAGE_LOCALIZATION_ID = t3.id 
WHERE (t0.LANGUAGE_ID = ? AND t1.ISO6391ALPHA2CODE IN (?, ?)) [params=?, ?, ?]
```

(Which brings up the question of why it has both `t1` *and* `t3`, but this is something of a lesser concern at the moment.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was wrong -
I'd mapped the one-to-many maps to key off the wrong columns.  The definition of `LanguageData` needed to be changed to:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LANGUAGE")
public class LanguageData extends PersistedAuditedData<Long> {

@Id
@Column
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "ISO6391ALPHA2CODE")
private String iso6391Alpha2Code;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "languageData")
@MapKeyColumn(name = "LANGUAGE_LOCALIZATION_ID")
private Map<Long, LanguageDataLocalization> localizations;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "localizationLanguage")
@MapKeyColumn(name = "LANGUAGE_ID")
private Map<Long, LanguageDataLocalization> languagesLocalized;

/**
 * Private no-arg constructor for reflection-based construction inside JPA providers.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private LanguageData() {
    // Fields initialized by JPA.
}

// Plus getters for fields
}
```

My concept of the maps were supposed to contain was correct, but I wasn't thinking through how they were supposed to be keyed (off of the *other* column).

Answer (score 0):

Can you enable SQL generation debug so that we can see what the sql code really is?

In hibernate its something like:
    `<property name = "hibernate.show_sql" value = "true" />`

Comment: Sorry, probably should have added that to begin with.  Question edited to include this information.